# A question about 2.1 Proposition on Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> 1. Definition of **measurable space**:
>
> If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$(Power set of $X$) is a $\sigma$-algebra, $(X, \mathcal{M})$ is called a **measurable space** and the sets in $\mathcal{M}$ are called **measurable sets**.
>
> 2. Definition of **$(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$-measurable**:
>
> If $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ are measurable spaces, a mapping $f: X->Y$ is called **$(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$-measurable**, or just **measurable** when $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are understood, if $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $E \in \mathcal{N}$.

**2.1 Proposition** from Folland's Real Analysis Modern Techniques:

If $\mathcal{N}$ is generated by $\mathcal{E}$, then $f: X -> Y$ is $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$-measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $E \in \mathcal{E}$.

What I'm confusing about is if $\mathcal{N}$ does being generated by $\mathcal{E}$, or say $\mathcal{N} = \sigma(\mathcal{E})$, is there any relationship between $Y$ and $\mathcal{E}$? Should Y be necessarily a subset of $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{E}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$, so a family of subsets of $Y$. $Y$ may or may not be  a member of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $Y$ must be a subset of $\mathcal{N}$ which is generated by $\mathcal{E}$. So $\mathcal{N}$ can be produced by two different methods? emmmm, I feel it weird.

Comment: No, $Y$ must be an _element_ of $\mathcal{N}$. In fact it is the largest (by inclusion) element of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry, my mistake. The largest element, yes, make sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer: an arbitary element of $\mathcal{E}$ must be a subset of $Y$?

Comment: All elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are subsets of $Y$, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclude from Daniel Fisher's comment,

$\mathcal{E}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ (power set of $Y$). Measurable space $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ requires $\mathcal{N}$ must be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ while $Y$ must contain the fullest staffs and be a element of $\mathcal{N}$. At the same time, $\mathcal{N}$ can play a role of generated $\sigma$-algebra of some set $\mathcal{E}$.